# Nginx locations

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-location

I'm working on a multi-tenant application in React and some clients want to upload .html files to the root of the project to use google console and things like that. I would not like all those files to be mixed with the application code so apart from the following code:

```
location / {
   try_files $ uri /index.html = 404;
}
```

I would like to add in NGINX a location block that allows me to divert to another folder any other .html file that starts in /, excluding cases like /static/example.html.

Example:

```
/               -> React default
/static/*.html  -> React default
/*.html         -> Derive to new folder
```

I would appreciate any help in this regard.

I tried something like this...

```
location /*.html {
    root /extras_folder;
}
location / {
    root /project_folder;
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
}
```

But does not work

Comment: Does each tenant have his own (sub)domain?

Comment: That's correct, each client has its own subdomain

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adheres to the rules you described:

```
    location ^~ /index.html {
        root /project_folder;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/[^/]+\.html {
        root /extras_folder;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        root /project_folder;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
```

- Second block is a regex match only on *.html in the root path
- Third block is for all other paths
- First block is to cover the edge case of / being /index.html - regex rules otherwise always get priority over path location blocks

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /project_folder;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @extras_folder;
        }

        location @extras_folder {
                root /extras_folder;
                try_files $uri @index_html;
        }

        location @index_html {
                try_files /index.html =404;
        }
}
```

This looks in `/project_folder` first, in `/extras_folder` second and, if still no file is found finally serves `/project_folder/index.html` (or 404 if that file doesn't exist).
You'd put uploaded files into `/extras_folder` in this case.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would mean that "new_folder" would be in the same root, that is, the same project code, only within a folder. The ideal would be a new location block with a root to another folder.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I updated my answer to enable a completely different `root`.